With Quarkus, how to exclude openapi extension in production build
New to Quarkus.
I am using Quarkus with io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi. My requirement is to keep the binary as small as possible. I dont need the openapi endpoint or swagger-ui in production build.
Is it possible to somehow exclude io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi from production build?
I am currently not using any annotations in the code. But if I want to use them, it would be nice if those could be stripped during priduction build and production binary only contains necessary code.

What is the exact overhead you are seeing?
if you don't use any annotations, openapi or swagger-ui the simplest is to just not include io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi.
if its because you just use the defaults and just use in devmode - then maybe add it as a profile so not used in a specific prod build?
and finally if you really want to tweak and cut out specific resources take a look at How to exclude resource file from quarkus fast jar which shows a way to cut out specific resources.
